# Synchronizing Files

Tags: java, php, c++

I have a project in which a file has to be synchronized across computers.

My problem is that my program gives an error that it runs out of execution time of 30 sec.

Now, i have made a program in php for this;
what it does is divides old file into blocks and makes md5 hashes of each block and compares 
it with modified file by dynamically making hashes of given length at any offset.(from starting till the end of modified file) And this way it finds the blocks which need not be transferred.

Any one out there has any experience,advice,links or code your more than welcome.Thnx

p.s i have the luxury to work in php, java or c++.

the code i'm giving is for testing purpose, it takes 2 files from same location(one modified file and the other the original) makes hashes of blocks from old file and compares it with hashes from new file at every other offset. hope this helps:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php  
   $k=0;
   $old_file = file_get_contents('11.jpg');
   $new_file = file_get_contents('12.jpg'); 
   $block_length = 2048;
   $j = 0;
   $md5_hashes_old = array();
   $md5_hashes_new = array();
   $diff_blocks = array(); 
   $first_char=array();
   $k = 0;
   while(1){
     if($j >strlen($old_file))
     break;
     $block = substr($old_file,$j,$block_length);
     $md5_hashes_old[$k] = md5($block);
     $first_char[$k]=$block[0];
     $j = $j+$block_length;
     $k++;
  } 
   $j = 0;
   $k = 0;
   $no_of_blocks = sizeof($md5_hashes_old);
   echo $no_of_blocks;
   $matched_blocks = array();
   $matched = 0;
   $fc=0;
   echo $md5_hashes_old[1].'</br>';
  for($i=0;$i<$no_of_blocks;$i++){
      $j =0;
      while(1){
    $block = substr($new_file,$j,$block_length);
    $md5_hash = md5($block);
    if($md5_hashes_old[$i] == $md5_hash){
        $match_block = array();
        $match_block['block_no'] = $i;
        $match_block['index'] = $j;
        array_push($matched_blocks,$match_block);
        break;
    }   
    else
        $j++;

    if($j > strlen($new_file))
        break;
    echo 'old='.$md5_hashes_old[$i].' i='.$i.' new='.$md5_hash.'</br>';
}       
}       
print_r($matched_blocks);   
?> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you're reinventing `rsync`...

Comment: could you please post the code that you experience problems with? any language you want will do.

Comment: Do you have the luxury of using rsync?

Comment: yeah, well i have used the concept of rsync. And also i've studied other projects such as dropbox and delta encoding and other methods related. 

but for the time being i cant get this concept to work because comparisons between every offset is very inefficient and results in timeout.....any suggestions!!

Comment: Maybe the problem is that md5 is slow try something faster like sha1.

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the time out is your first port of call.

I assume you are only doing the md5 comparison when you have a more recent modified date and the file length is different.

If you were using C++ you could use file system watchers to be notified when files are modified and then use that to trigger your process or to trigger the creation of the hash.

Another trick would be to cache files for making a binary diff:

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette

Answer (score 0):

You always can apply the dirty trick:

```
<?php  set_time_limit(9999);  ?>
```

But I'm agree with @aioobe, sounds like a reinvented `rsync`.

Comment: well yes, i would totally agree with you guys that this is similar to rsync an that i have used the concept of rsync. 
But my problem here is 
that comparing block with every other in modified file is very inefficient and because of which i have the problem of timeout.

any suggestions or tricks to improve upon speed of execution and actually make it to work.....thnx

Comment: Why don't you disable the limit by using 0?